In a higher topos, are any two global elements into a connected object homotopic?
Let H be an $\infty$-topos in the sense of Lurie. Let $X\in $H be a pointed and 1-connective object, meaning any point $1\to X$ is an effective epimorphism. Classicaly, in the $\infty$-topos of spaces $\mathcal{S}$, these are the connected spaces. I am interested in proving that, as in the classical case, any choices of points $x,y:1\to X$ yield isomorphic homotopy groups, i.e. $\pi_1(X,x)\cong\pi_1(X,y)$.
Homotopy groups can be defined as the 0-truncations of the loop space at the corresponding point, i.e. $\pi_1(X,x):= \tau_{\leq0}(\Omega_xX)$. Since loop spaces  naturally have a group structure and truncation preserves finite products, there is indeed an induced group structure on $\pi_1(X,x)$.
Since the loop space of $X$ at $x$ is the pullback of $x:1\to X$ along itself, it suffices to show that any two points $x,y:1\to X$ are homotopic.
Question: Are any two maps $x,y:1\to X$ homotopic ?
In Proposition 3.9 of this nlab page, it is stated that such maps are unique, hence answering positively the question (without proof). On the other hand, the statement that such maps are unique is part of the hypothesis of Lemma 3.9 of the article "Principal $\infty$-Bundles" of Nikolaus, Schreiber and Stevenson, suggesting that there exists counter examples.

I'm quite confused. In HTT Def 6.5.1.10 an object $X$ is $1$-connective if $X \to 1$ is an effective epimorphism but here in the pointed setting somehow $1 \to X$ takes that role? I would have expected a pointed $1$-connected object to be a map $1 \to X$ such that $X \to 1$ is an effective epimorphism. On the other hand, it seems like Nikolaus-Schreiber-Stevenson do what you do, so I must be confused about something.

This uniqueness condition from Lemma 3.9 in Nikolaus-Schreiber-Stevenson is actually not in the published version anymore. Though, the authors don't use any uniqueness but rather replaced the proof by a slightly more elaborate argument.

@QiZhu, the definition states that $X$ is $1$-connective if $X\to 1$ is an effective epimorphism and $\pi_0(X)\simeq 1$, i.e. it is connected. When $X$ is pointed, $X\to 1$ is necessarily an eff. epi, and HTT 6.5.1.20 says that $X$ is $1$-connective iff $1\to X$ is an eff. epi. This is intuitive since it means that $\pi_0(1)\to\pi_0(X)$ is an epimorphism in the $1$-topos of discrete objects ("$X$ has a unique connected component"). Thanks for noting the published version's modification! Their argument supports my question's affirmative answer, though their remark 2.21 raises doubt again...

Thanks for the explanation, that makes sense. I'm also not so sure if the published version is helpful, perhaps rather the opposite. I just saw that the arXiv version is more recent (2023) and the modification says "v2: published version; v3: missing assumption added to Lemma 3.9", which is precisely the assumption you're asking about. So it seems like the condition is needed! Perhaps asking one of the authors would be a helpful option!

Oh thanks for being more careful than me about the different versions! So I think that I can prove that global points into a connected object are essentially unique if the topos H $=$ Sh$(\mathcal{C},\mathcal{T})$, where $\mathcal{T}$ is a Grothendieck topology on a small $\infty$-category $\mathcal{C}$ which has a final object.  That is if my topos arises as a topological localization of a presheaf category. I'll try to find a counter example in a cotopological localization and post it here if I do!

I asked Urs about it. Let me quote him because I doubt I can explain better than him!

Dear Qi,
take X to be a topological space (or scheme, etc.) and let the
infinity topos be one of infinity-sheaves over this fixed X, then the
terminal object * is X itself, * = X, so that maps * --> BG are really
maps X --> BG and already correspond to principal G-bundles over X. So
unless in cases like where X is contractible, there will be
in-equivalent such maps.
This is an example of what is sometimes called a "petit topos".
In contrast, the condition that there is an essentially unique * -->
BG is a property shared by toposes that one will want to call "gros
toposes" (such as cohesive toposes). This "gros topos"-situation is
the case we really have in mind in the article.
Best wishes, urs

Nonetheless, here is my interpretation of the answer.
Let $X$ be a topological space (viewed as an object in $\mathcal{S}$) and consider $\mathsf{Sh}(X)$. Then, $*_{\mathsf{Sh}(X)} \simeq y(X)$ where I denote by $y$ the Yoneda embedding. Moreover, let $G$ be a topological group, viewed as $G \in \mathsf{Grp}(\mathcal{S})$ and consider $y(BG) \in \mathsf{Sh}(X)$. We claim $By(G) \simeq y(BG)$. Indeed, $\Omega y(BG) \simeq y(\Omega BG) \simeq y(G)$ using that $y$ commutes with limits. Moreover, $y(G) \in \mathsf{Grp}(\mathsf{Sh}(X))$. So a map $$ *_{\mathsf{Sh}(X)} \simeq y(X) \to y(BG) \simeq By(G)$$ corresponds to a map $X \to BG$ which corresponds to an (ordinary) principal $G$-bundle. There will be multiple ones of these in general cases!
So it seems that even though ($\infty$-)topoi are advertised as the place to do geometry, connectivity does not behave as one would naively expect from spaces.

Thanks for sharing your communications! Also if you work in a slice $\infty$-topos $\mathcal{E}/X$ and $A\in\mathcal{E}$ is connected, then global points into the connected object $A\times X$ of $\mathcal{E}/X$ correspond to maps $X\to A$, which of course are non unique.
